# django admin duplicating objects

Tags: python, django

I have been creating a permissions based on country part to my website for the admin console.

I have overridden the `save_model()` method on my class, which inherits from the `admin.ModelAdmin` class, with this:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    try:
        form_cleaned_countries = [self.get_field(c,self.country_field).pk for c in form.cleaned_data[self.country_field.split('__')[0]]]
    except TypeError:
        form_cleaned_countries = [self.get_field(form.cleaned_data[self.country_field.split('__')[0]], self.country_field).pk]

    type_of = 'change' if change else 'add'
    cbp = [c.country.pk for c in self.get_country_based_permissions(request, self.app_model, type_of)]

    valid = True
    countries_not_valid_for = []
    for c in form_cleaned_countries:
        if not c in cbp:
            valid = False
            countries_not_valid_for.append(Country.objects.get(pk=c))

    if not valid:
        raise Exception('You do not have the permission to \'%s\' on %s for %s.' % (type_of, self.model, countries_not_valid_for))

    print 'Saving....'
    super(CountryBasedPermissionsAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

After the method has run, when it takes you back to the admin page of the list of the model you just added or changed, the new object is there twice, and both links go to the exact same place. They have the exact same pk. And when i click on the link to edit the object in the admin console it errors with this:

> 'get() returned more than one VisaType -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were {'pk': 31}'

I was just curious if anyone else has had this issue with django or the admin console?

Comment: i have also gotten this error, so far haven't found a fix :(, its not only with the admin though

Comment: I fixed my error actually. The queryset function i was overridding was returning duplicate results, and the admin was just freaking out, even tho the duplicate results weren't actually in the database. Just added a distinct() onto the end of my queryset and it seems to be working.

Comment: If you fix it yourself, post the solution as an answer (not a comment) and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error actually. The queryset function i was overridding was returning duplicate results, and the admin was just freaking out, even tho the duplicate results weren't actually in the database. Just added a distinct() onto the end of my queryset and it seems to be working.